# Python3.6.2 shell on TAB pressed inserts tab character instead of autocomplete. How to fix it?

Tags: python, shell

I've installed python 3.6.2 from source on Linux Mint 17. Also I've python 3.4.3 with OS installation. Just noticed that autocompete on TAB in interactive shell works only in 3.4.3. In 3.6.2 it just inserts tab character.

Any solutions?

Comment: If you don't have a `readline` library, you're going to need one. Dunno what you'd install to get that on Mint.

Comment: (Does scrolling through command history with the arrow keys work?)

Comment: @user2357112 No. When i press UP ARROW `^[[A` appears. In 3.4 it really goes to previous history item.

Comment: That definitely sounds like you're missing readline.

Answer (score 1):

Autocomplete and navigating history in python shell uses readline library (and module). You can check its availability by `import readline`.

1. Install readline-dev library by `sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev`
2. Recompile python

Appreciation for @user2357112 !